# macro to extract dates from a weeks date range string and add 7 days to print next date range

Tags: date, range, addition, visual-studio-macros

I am writing a macro that processes an excel with lots of data. One of the rows contains a date range like wkstartdate - wkenddate and I would like to use dateadd function to print next date range every week (like **'27-01-14 - 02-02-14'** in below case) but unable to do so. 
**'06-01-14 - 12-01-14'
'13-01-14 - 19-01-14'
'20-01-14 - 26-01-14'**
I used below excerpt which fails:

```
Range("E" & Lastrow).Select
prwk = Split(ActiveCell.Value, "-")
'curr_wkstart = DateAdd("d", 7, prwk(1)) 'error as maybe prwk(1) isnt correct format
'curr_wkend = DateAdd("d", 7, prwk(2))   'error 
Range("E" & Lastrow + 1).Value = curr_wkstart & curr_wkend  'no result
```

For testing purpose I print, prwk(1) which is **20/01/14** in the above case, in a diff cell and add 7 days, which gives me **1/21/2020** instead of **'27/01/14'**. I also tried using Cdate function, but still error

Can you please advise??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to use here are the `Format` and `DateSerial` functions. Here's how I came at it:

```
Function GetNextWeek(TheStartWeek)
    a = Split(TheStartWeek, " - ")
    b = Split(a(1), "-")
    c = DateSerial(b(2), b(1), b(0)) + 1
    d = c + 6
    GetNextWeek = Format(c, "dd-mm-yy") & " - " & Format(d, "dd-mm-yy")
End Function

Sub Test()
    Debug.Print GetNextWeek("13-01-14 - 19-01-14") 'Givs you "20-01-14 - 26-01-14"
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: GEtting error 'Subscript out of range error' at the line number 4 where c is defined. Please further advise.

Comment: Hi Jim, great .. just a typo at line 3 " b = Split(a(1), "/") "  works well now.. Thank You :)